# Allow text selection only from one div at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two DIVs with the class "col-lg-6" (bootstrap) which makes them sit side by side. What I am trying to do is to only allow users to select text from one of these DIVs at a time. If he tries to select text from both DIVs in the same time, an error should be displayed.

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vm7psdt2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        First Paragraph
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
       Second Paragraph
    </div>
</div>
```

The user should only be allowed to select "First Paragraph" OR "Second Paragraph" at a time. Not text from both (eg: "First Paragraph Second" ).

I want this done with javascript or Jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/zj5tdpwy/

Minor thing you can tweak is you need to click on div and then select.

There is no direct solution in SO for this but hints are there: (Hopefully this post will solve Jquery way with CSS)

- [Is there a way to make a DIV unselectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924916/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-div-unselectable)
- [How to allow text-selection of a DIV, but prevent the text-selection of the father DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767924/how-to-allow-text-selection-of-a-div-but-prevent-the-text-selection-of-the-fath)

API:

- `.siblings` - http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Have a play around it will help `:)`

**Jquery Code**

```
 $(document).on('click','div',function() { 
        $(this).removeClass('unselectable').siblings().addClass('unselectable');
 });
```

**CSS**

```
*.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}

*.unselectable * {
   -moz-user-select: text;
   -khtml-user-select: text;
   -webkit-user-select: text;
   -o-user-select: text;
   user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: I made it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zj5tdpwy/1/

it is PERFECT! THANKS SO MUCH!

Comment: @MariusS `:)` you got it! Glad it helped!! +1 to you as well!

Comment: what about somebody is selecting the text by keyboard instead of mouse!

Comment: It does not matter. I have a function tied to mouse selection only. For what I need, Tats_innit's answer is perfect!